# NestJs - CLI Plugin - enabling the Swagger plugin for npm dependencies

Tags: npm, dependencies, nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-swagger

I created a npm DTO library used on different projects (front / back)

On the back side, I use NestJs and I would like to activate the Swagger CLI-Plugin of NestJs (https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin) on the created library, any idea how to do it?